# How to Hide URL Loading In Status Bar?

Tags: javascript, html

how to hide URL Loading In Status Bar in IE and Firefox?

Comment: but.. why would you want to do that?

Comment: @rochal - the most obvious answer to your question would be that you are loading some data from a third-party supplier and don't want people to know. For example, if you use Google Analytics, it will display "Loading www.google....." in the status bar. I have chosen this as it is a genuine reason for needing this function (although due to many non-genuine reasons it can't be done).

Answer (score 4):

You used to be able to manually set the status of the window using...

```
window.status = "Hello World";
```

However, most browsers stopped you from doing this a while back as it was used as a technique to direct users to phishing websites (i.e. you'd hover over a link that was pointing to "www.fakebank.com" and they would update the window status to "www.realbank.com" to make you think it was a genuine link.

So the short answer is, you won't be able to control what happens on the browser window, such as progress bar and URL being loaded as the browser won't allow it.