# Masking URL in Status Bar

Tags: php, javascript, html, ubuntu-server, url-masking

I'm hosting my own website on my personal server running Ubuntu server. My public IP address is showing up in the status bar each time someone visits my sites or hovers over one of the links on the pages (i.e. when going to the home page it says waiting for myipaddress/index.php). I have purchased a domain name with godaddy. While I was able to find the option of mask the url in the address bar in the admin page, I was able to find no such option for the status page. Initially, I tried to embed JavaScript code into the php files but I later learnt from various posts ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450654/how-to-hide-url-loading-in-status-bar)) that we cannot control what is displayed in the status bar .

All I want to do is to display my domain name instead of my IP address each time the page loads and each time the user hover's over a link. Any ideas of how I should go about this?

Comment: What's the value of the `href` attributes of the links? Do they include the IP? If yes, you have to fix the problem there. Also try the [`base` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) and set the host correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You should just have your domain name point to your IP address and setup the site on your server to handle that domain. Then all requests will go to that domain name instead of directly to your IP address.

Note: it's very easy to find the IP address for any web server (based on a domain name) so you can't really hide it, but you can set it up so that it behaves just like any regular site that uses a domain name instead of an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done anything to connect the webserver and the domain name?  You're going to need name servers, often your domain provider will have something you can use, or you can run your own.  The name server is like a phone book for websites. It says mydomain.com can be found at IP address 123.whatever.  Until you have an entry in a name server 'phone book' you will not be able to access it through that domain name.

You'll also need to setup something on the webserver so it will know what to serve when it gets a request pointed to that domain, if you're using apache, likely it will be a virtual host entry in the appropriate config file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I am not too familiar with name servers, but isn't the name server in my case up to date since when I type in my domain name in the address bar it brings me to my website (i.e. my domain name points to my IP address). Or, is there something else which I have to do?

Comment: Ah ok, no you're good then on the name servers then.  It's going to be something in your HTML which is causing your problem.